# Does Visual Studio 2008 have integration with SourceSafe?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition. In previous versions, there has been integration with VSS, through which one could "open from SourceSafe" and then, in the solution view, have the ability to interact with the source control by clicking on individual files. I seem to have some integration under 2008, namely there is a "Source Control" menu item under the File menu, but all I can do there is "Launch Microsoft Visual SourceSafe." How do I get the integration that I had in 2005?

Comment: Just as a side note...Sourcesafe is not a good solution for source control.  Consider Subversion and VisualSVN, much more stable and feature rich than SS.

Comment: Or TFS, which is now cheap for smaller "workgroup" sites.

Answer (score 8):

You have to install the VSS client software, and if you want the auto check out, etc. the project has to be bound to the source control repository.

Also try looking in the Tools -> Options -> Source control menu item.

Answer (score 4):

In order to enable Visual Source Safe 2005 integration with Visual Studio 2008, you just need to instal a small update:

[Visual SourceSafe 2005 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=8A1A68D8-DB11-417C-91AD-02AAB484776B&displaylang=en)

http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=8A1A68D8-DB11-417C-91AD-02AAB484776B&displaylang=en

---

For more information:

[List of bugs that are fixed in the Visual SourceSafe 2005 Update](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/943847)

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/943847

Answer (score 2):

You can click File -> Open -> Project/Solution and one of the side options is Microsoft Visual SourcsSafe.  You can select which VSS database you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

I have a standalone "Microsoft Visual SourceSafe" (2005) application on my machine. Is there a separate "client" component for VS 2008? I installed VSS before installing VS. Does that makes a difference?

In Tools -> Options -> Source Control, I have three options in the dropdown: "None," "Microsoft Visual SourceSafe," and "Microsoft Visual SourceSafe (Internet)."

Comment: Which one is selected? If "Microsoft Visual SourceSafe" is selected, it should "just work." (Always has for me.) (PS: SourceSafe is available via internet? Egad that's scary!)

Comment: @John -- if it does it via "Internet" it just uses webservices instead of a local protocol, I think.

Comment: I still stand by my statement -- for SourceSafe, egad that's scary! :) (Other version control systems, no problem, but VSS ... )

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the settings in this dropdown.

Until I find a way to get the solution explorer integration working correctly, I am running VSS client in a separate window and checking out files by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to solve your problem. Just FYI, I recently installed Visual Studio 2008 alongside my existing Visual Studio 2005 installation, and it worked automatically. VS 2008 was integrated with SourceSafe with absolutely no configuration from me. Sorry it didn't work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue.  VSS integration in VS2008 doesn't seem to be working as expected.  It is aware of where my VSS repository is for my project but if I attempt to edit a checked-in file it just asks if I want to make it write-able... well no, I want to check it out but that's not an option.

SO I too am using the VSS client on the side abd checking files in and out manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should close Visual Studio and install the update again. It works for me